# String array in visual c++ form

Tags: arrays, string, c++-cli

I have created empty C++/CLI form in Microsoft Visual Studio.

What I want to do is to keep car brands in one array and car models in other array.
Then I will draw one brand, to put it on label, one car model that is from that brand and 3 other car models from other brands.

In my form i want to create 2 arrays:

```
String brands[7]={"Mercedes","Opel","Toyota","Fiat","Audi","Renault","Volkswagen"};
String models[7][5]={{"Benz","Vito","AMG","Klasa A","Klasa E"},
                     {"Astra","Corsa","Insignia","Zafira","Mokka"},
                     {"Avensis","Corolla","Yaris","Auris","RAV4"},
                     {"126p","Panda","Punto","500","Tipo"},
                     {"A4","A6","Q7","R8","A7"},
                     {"Megane","Captur","Scenic","Kadjar","Espace"},
                     {"Golf","Passat","Tiguan","Beetle","Touran"}};
```

I can't put it anywhere in my MyForm.h file, I am getting E2022 error. 
What simple solution would you suggest me?

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Podsumowanie informacji o MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: W tym miejscu dodaj kod konstruktora
            //
        }


    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Wyczyść wszystkie używane zasoby.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    String marki[7]={"Mercedes","Opel","Toyota","Fiat","Audi","Renault","Volkswagen"};
    String modele[7][5]={{"Benz","Vito","AMG","Klasa A","Klasa E"},
                     {"Astra","Corsa","Insignia","Zafira","Mokka"},
                     {"Avensis","Corolla","Yaris","Auris","RAV4"},
                     {"126p","Panda","Punto","500","Tipo"},
                     {"A4","A6","Q7","R8","A7"},
                     {"Megane","Captur","Scenic","Kadjar","Espace"},
                     {"Golf","Passat","Tiguan","Beetle","Touran"}};

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Wymagana zmienna projektanta.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Wymagana metoda obsługi projektanta — nie należy modyfikować 
        /// zawartość tej metody z edytorem kodu.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 

            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 108);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(147, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(178, 108);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(146, 23);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 183);
            this->button3->Name = L"button3";
            this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(147, 23);
            this->button3->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(178, 183);
            this->button4->Name = L"button4";
            this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(146, 23);
            this->button4->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(178, 250);
            this->button5->Name = L"button5";
            this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(146, 23);
            this->button5->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button5->Text = L"Nastepne";
            this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button5_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(140, 28);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(0, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(361, 306);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"QUIZ";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

}
};
}
```

Comment: What message of E2022 is? I do not want to google it.

Comment: Need more context, please create an [mcve].

Comment: Is the error during compilation or run-time?

Comment: [How to: Use Arrays in C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli).

Comment: Added full header code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to do:

First declare your arrays under protected section (as you did there).

```
array<String^>^ marki;
array<String^,2>^ modele; //Note the declration 2 next to String^. It is rank of the array. 2 for two dimensional.
```

And in your constructor (`MyForm()` ) intialize your arrays as shown below.

```
//SINGLE DIMENSION ARRAY
marki = gcnew array<String^> {"Mercedes","Opel","Toyota","Fiat","Audi","Renault","Volkswagen"};

//MULTI DIMENSIONAL ARRAY
modele = gcnew array<String^,2> {{"Benz","Vito","AMG","Klasa A","Klasa E"},
                     {"Astra","Corsa","Insignia","Zafira","Mokka"},
                     {"Avensis","Corolla","Yaris","Auris","RAV4"},
                     {"126p","Panda","Punto","500","Tipo"},
                     {"A4","A6","Q7","R8","A7"},
                     {"Megane","Captur","Scenic","Kadjar","Espace"},
                     {"Golf","Passat","Tiguan","Beetle","Touran"}};
        }
```

Testing:

```
String^ test = modele[2,4]; //RAV4
```